# npm run won't execute properly through CMD

Tags: laravel, docker, nginx, docker-compose, vite

So I have this one project built on Laravel, React and Vite using Docker.
Inside there are "app" container (which contains the app itself) and "nginx" container which works as a proxy (tbh I don't know why didn't they put nginx in the "app" container, but there might be some reason).

When I try to run it through docker-compose.yml everything seems to be ok, but I have to execute "npm run dev" in the "app" container manually - then app starts as it should. But if I put "npm run dev" as a CMD in Dockerfile or as command: in docker-compose.yml, output says that everything is up but I keep getting 502.
I found that issue might be something about "nginx" container connecting to "app"'s fastcgi, but still I don't know how to fix it.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.2-fpm-alpine3.18

RUN apk update && apk upgrade --no-cache
RUN apk add --no-cache git curl zip unzip nodejs npm python3 alpine-sdk apk-cron openrc
RUN rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

RUN mv "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-production" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"

COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

WORKDIR /var/www
COPY --chown=www-data . .

RUN chmod -R ugo+rwx /var/www
RUN cd /var/www && composer install && npm install && php artisan key:generate
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"

services:
    nginx:
        container_name: nginx
        image: "nginx:latest"
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
        volumes:
            - "./.docker-compose/nginx/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/"
            - "data:/var/www"
        networks:
            - local
        restart: on-failure
        depends_on:
            - app
        links:
            - app

    app:
        container_name: app
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        #command: npm run dev
        ports:
            - "5173:5173"
        volumes:
            - "data:/var/www/"
        networks:
            - local
        restart: on-failure

networks:
    local:
        driver: bridge

volumes:
    data:
```

I've tried putting the "npm run dev" on cron but that doesn't seem to fix the issue.
crond (executed through CMD) output says that everything is up, but I'm still getting 502. If I run crond in container manually, it works well. At this point I'm kinda desperate :(

Comment: A Docker container only runs a single process.  If you need a Node dev server alongside the reverse proxy and the PHP server, it should be a separate container.

Comment: @DavidMaze it is in separate "nginx" container